# How to fold (all types of) comments in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Netbeans seems inconsistent with folding comments in my Java code. Sometimes I can fold the comments, and sometimes I cannot. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can also include something like

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="stuff to be collapsed">
/* start of comment
...
*/
// </editor-fold>
```

Answer (score 3):

Right click on you Java code navigate to

> Code Folds -> Collapse All Javadoc

This will fold all the comments....

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have functions with very long lines, I usually do this

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Description (Example Execute)">
 /**
 *
 * Execute the query
 *
 * Accepts an SQL string as input and returns a result object upon
 * successful execution of a "read" type query. Returns boolean TRUE
 * upon successful execution of a "write" type query. Returns boolean
 * FALSE upon failure, and if the $db_debug variable is set to TRUE
 * will raise an error.
 *
 * @param   string  $sql
 * @param   array   $binds = FALSE      An array of binding data
 * @param   bool    $return_object = NULL
 * @return  mixed
 */

 public function query($sql, $binds = FALSE, $return_object = NULL){
 /* exmample code here */
 }

 // </editor-fold>
```

I hope that will be useful :))

Answer (score 2):

Also Check:

> Tools --> Options -- > Editor

There are a heap of check boxes there to configure default folding.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why:

To fold code comments in java, you need two asterisks, like this:

/**

as opposed to just

/*

Comment: Aaah, that would be because /** is a Javadoc Comment, where as /* is just for multi-line "non-javadoc" comments.